# Run piece of code every x amount of time using the exception clause

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-s3, time

I need to write a code that is doing the following:

1. Continuously checking the existence of a file in AWS S3 every minute throwing a exception when nothing is found --- I'm aware of how to do this. I'm using a while loop for this.
2. Once in the exception, I would like for an email to be sent out every 60 min. Now is the tricky part, What can I do so that there is a time marker for every 60 min for the email to be sent out whilst I'm in the while loop?

```py
while True:
    try:
        result = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_buck, Key=s3_key)
        print(result)
        return
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(60)
        ***what do I do here?***
            my_email_function()
        continue
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This _definitely_ shouldn't be done inline like you're showing here. More likely you'd persist something to your database, e.g. a timestamp of the last time you found that file. Based on that timestamp you'd send email. That might be done by a simple CLI task you run every minute or every five minutes or something via cron. In pseudocode: `if (current_time - last_time_file_was_seen > 1 hour) then { send_email() }`. You'll probably want a second clause based on when the email was last sent.

Comment: @JUAmaned Please tell us more about your business requirements. How does the file appear, and will it every disappear? Why are you checking every minute, but only notifying after an hour? If the file is not present at Minute 1, but appears at Minute 5, then disappears at Minute 8, what should the code do? Please edit your question to provide the _higher-level goal_ that you are trying to achieve so that we can recommend the best solution.

Comment: Is your exception throwing code a requirement? It seems to me like you are simply trying to see if a file isn't there and if it never shows up you want to send an email. If so there are a number of options, and none of the options I'd suggest involve throwing exceptions.

Comment: So the file is upload to S3 by an EC2 instance and will not ever disappear. The check does not need to be every minute but every so often so that a completion email that the file is present is sent out immediately after discovering the file. The exception is not a requirement but the result command will throw an error if it does not find the file hence the exception.

Comment: So lets say that we execute the script....the first iteration does not find the file - the process will sleep a min since the file can appear anytime within 48 hours, it will sleep for 60 seconds and mark the time of the first iteration. 60 min after the time is marked, it will send out the email meanwhile the 60 second while loop is still ongoing to check for the existence of the file. Once the 60 min mark has been reached and no file is found, it will again send the email and so on. The file will not disappear so there is no need to worry about that.